# Ejecutar función antes de enviar formulario

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría ejecutar una función antes de enviar un formulario, pero al parecer nunca se ejecuta, ¿es posible ejecutarla antes de enviarlo sin usar atributos como `onsubmit="return funcion()"` o enviarlo con ajax?

Formulario HTML

```
         <form action="search" method="GET" class="form-search" name="s-627">
            <div class="search-container">
                <input class="searchBox" type="search" name="q" id="searchTerm">
                <button class="btn-form searchButton">
                    <span class="icon-search">s</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Código de JS

```
        let form = document.querySelector('.form-search')
            form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
              e.preventDefault()
              console.log('submit')
              //función a ejecutar antes de enviar
              saveSearch(input.value)
        })
```

Comment: Actualmente sería difícil realizarlo sin usar ninguno de los dos métodos que mencionas, yo te recomendaría hacerlo con el onsubmit, que va a exigir menos líneas de código.

Comment: @JonathanArias ¿Qué necesito hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar el evento `click` y ejecutar dentro la función y posteriormente forzar el submit. Algo como esto:

```js
let form = document.querySelector('.form-search')
    form.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('submit')
      //función a ejecutar antes de enviar
      saveSearch(input.value)
      
      form.submit();
})
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" name="in" value="some data" />
 <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo para clarificar, el proceso con el evento `onsubmit` sería realmente sencillo, ya que evitamos procesos elaborados:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
    res = saveSearch(input.value); //la función saveSearch deberá retornar true para poder que se cumpla.
    if(res){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

La ventaja es que el return false restringiría el envío en caso de que no se logre cumplir la otra función.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que primero definas un id en tu buttom y cambies de tipo ademas de agregar una funciona a su click, quedando así:

```
<button type="button" id="btn_prueba" class="btn-form searchButton" onclick="subir()">
    <span class="icon-search">s</span>
</button>
```

También asignale un id a tu formulario:

```
<form action="search" method="GET" id="my_form" class="form-search" name="s-627">
```

Entonces lo uníco que falta es hacer la función que asignaste al botón:

```
<script>
    function subir(){
        //aqui haces la llamada a otras funciones o realizas todo lo que quieres
        sumar(2,3);
        // y ahora subes el formulario
        document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
    }
    function sumar(a,b){
        return a+b;
    }
</script>
```

Espero te funcione.